# URI doesn't validate on W3C Markup Validator, identical direct input does

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, w3c, w3c-validation

I'm trying to get a site to validate as HTML5 on the [W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/). When I use the "Validate by URI" option, it generates a ton of errors, but when I copy and paste the HTML into the "Validate by direct input", it validates perfectly. When I run a diff on the two sources returned by the validator, the only differences are the Rails authenticity tokens (random strings Rails uses to validate forms - this is expected).

I've noticed that under both circumstances, I get a "No Character encoding declared at document level" warning, which I've seen on other sites but always assumed was a bug in the HTML5 validator, as I have an appropriate meta tag:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Most of the errors are something along the lines of the following:

- Quote " in attribute name. Probable cause: Matching quote missing somewhere earlier.
- Bad value for attribute for on element label: An ID must not be the empty string.
- Attribute "password" not allowed on element label at this point.

It acts like there's a mismatched quote, but I can't find anything wrong, and again, the identical direct input validates perfectly.

Any clue what's going on here? Thanks!

Comment: What `Content-Type` is being sent by the server? Does it include a `charset` and, if so, is it UTF-8?

Comment: I'm pretty inexperienced with HTTP headers, but I just checked using the Live HTTP Headers Firefox add-on and don't see any content-type parameters. Could this be causing the problem? Shouldn't it just fall back to the header in the document?

Comment: @WebDevHobo: Screenshot of the HTTP headers or W3C results?

Comment: I was going to say W3C result, but why not toss the headers in as well if you know how to get them(I sure don't)

Comment: I suspect that all of the errors are being caused by the Content-Type problem (especially since the markup validates perfectly when pasted into the validator). I'll check in later with the solution/more details. Thanks!

Comment: To update, it turns out I was looking at the request headers, not the response headers. The response has a content type of "text/html; charset=utf-8", which seems correct. I'm considering just chalking this up to a validator bug and moving on - whatever it's seeing doesn't seem to be a problem anywhere I've tested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [known bug](http://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=5992) in the W3C Perl layer. [Validator.nu](http://html5.validator.nu/) has the same back end but without the Perl layer.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a validator bug, in which case your page could be of interest to the validator developers. Please consider getting in contact with them: http://validator.w3.org/feedback.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Try using this instead:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: I've already tried that. It does cause the "No Character encoding declared at document level" warning to go away, but otherwise doesn't fix anything.

Comment: Although I agree what you recommend, putting it in the validator causes the following error: Bad value Content-Type for attribute http-equiv on XHTML element meta.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` including the closing forward slash